# What is the best approach to invoke a MSSQL procedure, which takes a large XML file as an argument?

Tags: java, sql-server, xml, t-sql, callable-statement

I am working on an app that inserts content of an XML file in [MSSQL](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=1279) DB, everytime app server is started.

The XML contains multiple records of related tables. The stored proc takes the XML file content as (TEXT) argument, creates a pointer ([sp_xml_preparedocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187367.aspx)) & inserts into tables using [OPENXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx).

I need to execute the procedure using JDBC (or may be [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms162773.aspx)) from the application server where the XML file resides.

The XML file is around 160MB, right now I am sending the XML file by reading as a large String object to the [CallableStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html), but its very time/space/resource consuming.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the accepted best practice but if I were doing it, I would consider that this is likely a candidate for the following approach:

1. transform the XML in to easily loadable files such as BCP compliant script
2. BCP/load the data into staging tables/temp tables
3. SQL merge the data. This has the advantage that you're able to optimise the SQL to your use case.

In which case there is no need to 'pass' a massive blob in memory and thus rely on the the advanced processing of SQL Server BCP loading technology as opposed to MSXML.

In such a scenario the calls to SQL are simple sp calls with parameters pointing to files.

---

If BCP is not your cup of tea then perhaps a simillar solution using SSIS may work.

---

Finally if you must use a XML file, then perhaps passing the name of the file to a SQL CLR procedure which will load it into SQL memory may be in order.